# INNER JOIN skipping key with the same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Im trying to filter my `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` so it can be used on a custom post type called `filmfremvisning` with a meta_key field with a date in it. The `filmfremvisning` CPT is some kind of "events" CPT where the event posts have an expiration date on them. The expiration date has the following format of `YYYYMMDD` and is named `dato_for_fremvisningen`.

I also have a custom post status called `expired` and a cronjob that gives all expired posts that status every night.

I have tried these two links:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139453/filter-next-post-link-and-previous-post-link-by-meta-key
- http://return-true.com/2012/04/custom-ordering-for-wordpress-post-link-functions/

And I got it working quite nice. The problem however is that the INNER JOIN is skipping posts that has the same date.

For example if I have the following posts and dates:

- Event 1 - 20140102
- Event 2 - 20140105
- Event 3 - 20140105
- Event 4 - 20140107

It returns:

- Event 1 - 20140102
- Event 2 - 20140105
- Event 4 - 20140107

The SQL statement is for furture post is:

```
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'filmfremvisning' 
  AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND m.meta_key = 'dato_for_fremvisningen' 
  AND m.meta_value > '$current_filmfremvisning_date' 
GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY m.meta_value ASC`
```

The code im using in `functions.php` is down below:

```
function get_adjacent_past_events_join($join) {
  if(is_singular('filmfremvisning')) {
    global $wpdb;
    $new_join = $join."INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id ";
    return $new_join;
  }
  return $join;
}
add_filter('get_previous_post_join', 'get_adjacent_past_events_join');
add_filter('get_next_post_join', 'get_adjacent_past_events_join');


function get_future_filmfremvisnings_where($where) {
  if(is_singular('filmfremvisning')) {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $current_filmfremvisning_date = get_field('dato_for_fremvisningen', $id);
    $new_where = "WHERE p.post_type = 'filmfremvisning' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND m.meta_key = 'dato_for_fremvisningen' AND m.meta_value > '$current_filmfremvisning_date'";
    return $new_where;
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('get_next_post_where', 'get_future_filmfremvisnings_where');


function get_past_filmfremvisnings_where($where) {
  if(is_singular('filmfremvisning')) {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $current_filmfremvisning_date = get_field('dato_for_fremvisningen', $id);
    $new_where = "WHERE p.post_type = 'filmfremvisning' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND m.meta_key = 'dato_for_fremvisningen' AND m.meta_value < '$current_filmfremvisning_date'";
    return $new_where;
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'get_past_filmfremvisnings_where');


function get_prev_past_filmfremvisnings_sort($sort) {
  if(is_singular('filmfremvisning')) {
    global $wpdb;
    $new_sort = " GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY m.meta_value DESC";
    return $new_sort;
  }
  return $sort;
}
add_filter('get_previous_post_sort', 'get_prev_past_filmfremvisnings_sort');


function get_next_future_filmfremvisnings_sort($sort) {
  if(is_singular('filmfremvisning')) {
    global $wpdb;
    $new_sort = " GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY m.meta_value ASC";
    return $new_sort;
  }
  return $sort;
}
add_filter('get_next_post_sort', 'get_next_future_filmfremvisnings_sort');
```